# A std::getline with list of stopping characters

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a `std::getline` function which is able to stop if it encounters any of the characters listed in a string, so I came up with the following:

```
std::istream& read_until(std::istream& is, std::string& s, const std::string& list) {
    s.clear();
    while (is.peek() && is && list.find(is.peek()) == list.npos) {
        s += is.get();
    }
    return is;
}
```

The fact that it leaves the terminating character on the stream is the desired behavior. This works, but it's ugly and doesn't feel the right way to go. I'd like to ask if you see any clear mistake or if you have a better way of handling this.

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: FWIW, here is a really spiffy way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41029063/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow the linked solution is really crazy! I'll try it and if unsatisfactory I'll move this question to CodeReview. Thanks.